# Calculate Working Days From Date Range

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

Given a range of dates, number of days needs to be calculated excluding holidays given and certain days each week(weekly offdays).

The holidays will be an `array` of dates but weekly offdays will just be a number, `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, representing days of the week.

The following is what i have tried so far:

```
export const calculateWorkingDays = (startDate, endDate, weeklyOffDays, holidays) => {
    // Get difference between start and end dates
    // Not used other parameters yet
    return startDate.diff(endDate, 'days');
}
```

I dont yet know how to get `weekly off days` dates from the number representation and also how to subtract given days(weekly off days and holidays) from date range then get remaining days count.

Comment: `The holidays will be an array of dates` so each day of the holidays will be in there? Like `[May1, May 2, May 3]` ?

Comment: @JonasW., yes for holidays is an array containing dates like the way you specified

Answer (score 1):

You can loop from `startDate` to `endDate` and check for each item if the the day of the week is included in `weeklyOffDays` or the day is included in the `holidays` array.

Here a live sample, supposing `weeklyOffDays` as array of integers and `holidays` as array of ISO 8601 strings.

```js
const calculateWorkingDays = (startDate, endDate, weeklyOffDays, holidays) => {
  let count = 0;
  const start = moment(startDate);
  const end = moment(endDate);
  while( start.isBefore(end) ){
    if( !weeklyOffDays.includes(start.day()) && !holidays.includes(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))){
      count++;
    }
    start.add(1, 'day');
  }
  return count;
}

const res = calculateWorkingDays('2018-07-01', '2018-07-15', [5, 6], ['2018-07-04']);
console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```